# Too many constructor arguments

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, constructor, arguments

I encounter this problem where I have to pass a lot of arguments to the constructor in order to instantiate the class. I have no clue how to tackle this problem.

```
user = SpecialStudent(John, Doe, johndoe@example.com, 0612345678, 9988778, hello)

class User(Base):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, email):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.email = email

class Student(User):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, email, phone, student_number):
        super(Student, self).__init__(name, surname, email)
        self.phone = phone
        self.student_number = student_number

class SpecialStudent(Student):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, email, phone, student_number, random_param):
        super(SpecialStudent, self).__init__(name, surname, email, phone, student_number)
        self.random_param = random_param
```

I have thought about the builder pattern or factory, but I don't know which pattern will tackle this problem or if there is a other way to do this.

Comment: Why is it a problem to you?

Answer (score 0):

after small modifications:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, email):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.email = email

class Student(User):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, email, phone, student_number):
        super(Student, self).__init__(name, surname, email)
        self.phone = phone
        self.student_number = student_number

class SpecialStudent(Student):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, email, phone, student_number, random_param):
        super(SpecialStudent, self).__init__(name, surname, email, phone, student_number)
        self.random_param = random_param

user = SpecialStudent("John", "Doe", "johndoe@example.com", "0612345678", "9988778", "hello")
```

1. your Base class is not defined
2. dont use constructor before class declaration
3. your inputs are not declared (in my code all inputs are strings)